# MVC4 403 forbidden error with siteminder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5, siteminder

We have a MVC4 application running on a windows server 2008 with iis 7.5. everything was running fine until out SSO team installed siteminder for single sign on.

Now the application after the SSO redirect is giving a 403 forbidden error. **Any Suggestions?**

Here's what is happening.
1. access the site.
2. Site redirects to SSO page
3. after entering the credentials (everything is validated as the siteminder trace and logs is showing no errors)
4. application redirects the original entered url and we see a 403.

we currently have no implementation that uses the SSO user coz we were waiting for the SSO to be setup and our current authentication in web config is set to "None"

application was all good before the siteminder and the url was accessible.

Verified everything but not sure what is the issue.
1. Application pool is set to 4.0
2. TestConnection is ok for authorization and authentication
3. No errors in siteminder logs (the SM cookie is set correctly)
4. We do not have SSL 
5. this is the only site running on the server
6. IIS_IUSRS is given access to the sites root folder

Not sure if there is anything we can do in the sites web config. though as i have mentioned before it was all ok before site minder. Now Even if we disable the siteminder the application just return 403 forbidden.

please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well we finally reached out to some people with extensive siteminder experience and they suggested to use the "classic" app pool instead of "Integrated" which solved our issue.